# How to connect to Wi-Fi AP through WPS?

Tags: wireless

How to connect to Wi-Fi AP through WPS? All ways will be nice: configs, CLI, GUI - anything.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Comment: I have no possibility to try solution for any time, but it seems good.

Comment: @user51072 Did you try it? do you have a working solution?

Comment: Its very good question but very complex answers :/ what is really interesting that on onther platforms its one click functionality... We might probably wait till there is better more stable way before accepting answer..

Comment: It would be very frustrating if it lacks this basic functionality.

Comment: @Jurosh One-click is what we want. Not 30 tedious steps that take minutes each time.

Comment: An older answer for LinuxMint, with a detailed walkthrough of   `wpa_cli`  https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=192554

Answer (score 13):

Tested using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

For WPS Push-button mode:

```
sudo wpa_cli wps_pbc
```

You can push the WPS button before or after this command, but you have two minutes to have the button pushed and this command ran or you'll have to do it all over again.

For WPS Pin mode:

```
sudo wpa_cli wps_pin any <the pin>
```

http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/external/bsd/wpa/dist/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Mint 17.3 and TP-Link TL-WR1043ND. Maybe "QSS" not the same as "WPS".

Comment: You are correct, QSS is not the same as WPS.... But this question is about WPS, so....

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Xenial. `wpa_cli status` returns `wpa_state=COMPLETED` (among other data), but I'm no more connected to the network than I was before. A couple of minutes later, I'm back to `wpa_state=INACTIVE` as a response.

Comment: This worked, however I also had to manually start dhcpcd (`sudo dhcpcd`) and the network icon in my taskbar showed no connection even though I could load webpages.

Answer (score 12):

> Solution from ryanjna...@gmail.com
> http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/issues/detail?id=203

1. Check your interface with this command

   `sudo wpa_cli wps_pin any`

   You will get "Selected interface **'your interface'** "
   when you see **Your_Interface** in the next commands know that you
   have to replace it with the Interface that you got from this
   command...
2. Stop the Network-Manager

   Using Upstart

   ```
    sudo stop network-manager
   ```

   Using Systemd

   ```
    sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
   ```
3. Set yourself up a very basic `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`. This command will overwrite any pre-exsiting wpa_supplicant.conf file!:

   ```
    echo -e "ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant\nctrl_interface_group=0\nupdate_config=1" | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```
4. Start `wpa_supplicant` in daemon mode:

   ```
    sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i**your_interface** -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```
5. Run `sudo wpa_cli`. This will start a interactive wpa_cli session.

- Verify that it's working by issuing command `status`.
  You should see `wpa_state=INACTIVE`
- Issue `scan` to scan for existing access-points.
- Issue `scan_result` after a few seconds to show the results from your scan
- Add our BSSID and PIN:

  ```
       wps_reg xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 12345678
  ```

  Where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is your BSSID from your scan results.
  You should see an "OK".  Wait a few more seconds as `wpa_supplicant` picks up the BSSID and tries to associate and perform key negotiation. What you want to see is `CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED`, which will indicate that the PIN was accepted and that you're now associated.
- Type the command `save`, which should output another "OK".  This will update the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, as specified from the command line, with a static configuration for this new network.
- Now exit `wpa_cli` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

5. Run `sudo dhclient **your_interface**` to get IP from the AP (assuming DHCPd were enabled).
6. Verify with `cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` your newly updated config-file.

If all went well, you should have a line under this new network titled `psk`.

Good luck!

Comment: Solution doesn't work. `ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument` using Ubuntu 12 LTS. Is there support in NM?

Comment: @Dejan I got that warning as well in Ubuntu 12 LTS -- solution still worked though.

Comment: @Seth Excuse me, as you know there is no wpa_supplicant.conf in Ubuntu 14.04. Could you please help me? Finally after getting a lots of error, in `sudo wpa_cli status` I got `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory` error.

Comment: @Daniyal You should ask a new question, comments aren't a good place for third party debugging :)

Comment: @Seth Thanks, could you please take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/705937/how-to-connect-to-wifi-with-wps-pin-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: So this needs  to be done  each time  instead   of clicking twice?

Comment: Isn't there any lesser tedious way? Who is ready to do _this_ every time?

Answer (score 2):

Connect through WPS on a windows setup, where it works out of the box.

Then open up the network settings on that setup, where it allows you to display the network password that was exchanged through WPS.

Copy that password to your ubuntu setup.

Comment: Don't know why this is being downvoted - it's a practical solution to the main reason this question is useful - that is *"I don't know the WIFI password, but I have WPS access, how can I connect?"* +1 This also work on android, with a root-mode file explorer, you can check the passwords in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: Ah, maybe the downvotes were for the comment about ubuntu being frustrating.  Here is [the relevant bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/388553) - go an subscribe to that, if you want WPS support.

Comment: Thanks for the Android tip, @naught101; worked beautifully from my rooted Nexus 7's terminal! :-)

Comment: It is being downvoted because we wish to use WPS immediately instead of rebooting twice.

Comment: @naught101 Do not take this personally, but this really needs to be downvoted. In fact, this is the first downvote I ever placed on AskUbuntu.com.

Comment: @neverMind9: No worries. You downvote it because it's not the "correct" way, and I'll upvote it because it works.

Comment: @naught101 Gladly you're satisfied.

Comment: @neverMind9 If you wish a working WPS, talk to the Ubuntu team. This site is for finding solutions and this answer is a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to type the password you should click on the WiFi indicator to select the WiFi network. Then, when the enter password screen appears, push the WPS button in the WiFi AP. This will automatically connect you without any password.

This works on my Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 machine. This method is [official but undocumented](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/925).

Comment: In what setup have you tested this solution ?

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 20.04. It even says you can press the WPS button of the AP in the "Enter network password" window.

Comment: Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The password dialog doesn't say a thing about WPS but it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed instructions from multiple posts above to complete the task as Xubuntu did not have a WPS of any kind that I could find.

1. Steps 1-3 from https://askubuntu.com/a/170799 .
2. This one to enable the actual push: https://askubuntu.com/a/769600 .
   In this case i used the push button not the pin.
3. And finish with a dhclient.

Linking a script to show how it works with comments. I hope it's ok to do this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# tadaen sylvermane | jason gibson
# connect to wps capable router via push button. yes we need a gui solution
# but this does it via terminal window. just run the script.

# https://askubuntu.com/questions/120367/how-to-connect-to-wi-fi-ap-through-wps

WIFIIF=$(grep wpa /proc/net/unix | cut -d \/ -f 4)
WPACONF=/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

# steps 1-3 https://askubuntu.com/a/170799

if [ "$USER" = root ] ; then
    # stop NetworkManager for this session
    systemctl stop NetworkManager
    # create wpa supplicant base file
    if [ ! -f "$WPACONF" ] ; then
        echo "ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1" > "$WPACONF"
    fi
    # start wpa_supplicant daemon
    wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i"$WIFIIF" -c "$WPACONF"
    # https://askubuntu.com/a/769600
    wpa_cli wps_pbc
    # go push the button!
    echo "push the wps button on the router now!"
    read -p "after wps button pushed type yes to connect or no to cancel -> " \
    yesno
    case "$yesno" in
        Y|y|yes|Yes|YES)
            dhclient
            wait
            ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 && echo "connected!" && exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            # cancel all above changes #
            rm "$WPACONF"
            kill $(ps aux | grep "$WIFIIF" | grep root | awk '{print $2}')
            systemctl start NetworkManager
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
else
    echo "must run as root or with sudo"
    exit 1
fi

# end script #
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I think is totally ok to link a script, but maybe You could just copy-pase it here? Please use "```" (triple backtick, without quote symbols) at the lines before and after the code to keep a correct formatting, Thank You in advance and for the answer!

Comment: i'll try that. im away from home on my laptop. tried the typical [code] tags bug didn't work. when i get home tomorrow evening ill make a direct post of the script.