# How to connect to WiFi with WPS pin in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, network-manager

Is there any way to connect to WiFi router with WPS pin? There is a  [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120367/how-to-connect-to-wi-fi-ap-through-wps#) for previous version of Ubuntu, but I have not wpa_supplicant.conf file.

wpa_gui react against correct pin and show "connected" (Does not show connected with incorrect pin), but I'm not actually connect to the router. Do you have any idea about that?

Also, I try create a file

```
$ cat wpa_supplicant.conf  
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant 
ctrl_interface_group=0  
update_config=1
```

And run

```
$ sudo killall wpa_supplicant 
$ sudo rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0 
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c wpss –B 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant 
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument 
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument 
^Cwlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

The last command stuck, so I pres ctrl + c.

```
$ wpa_cli status 
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Wi-Fi AP through WPS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120367/how-to-connect-to-wi-fi-ap-through-wps)

Comment: This is automatic with NetworkManager: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257859/1004020