# wpa_cli fails when I connect to my interface

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant

Following [How to connect to Wi-Fi AP through WPS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/120367/), I configured my `wpa_supplicant` (I'm trying to connect with WPS), the steps are these:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
echo -e "ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant\nctrl_interface_group=0\nupdate_config=1" | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

But when I run `wpa_cli`, I get:

```
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying
```

And when I use `wpa_cli -i wlan0`, I get:

```
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: wlan0 - re-trying
```

I must use `wpa_supplicant`. I want to save my password there. How I can solve these errors?

At last I got wpa_supplicant working but I get this error and I think when I am using wps wpa_cli never exits:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

[image: never finish and i think crashed]

When I try to use this:

```
sudo wpa_cli wps_pin mymac 68129231
```

that never finishes either. I dont know why wpa_supplicant can't work with `wpa_cli`. I can't use dhclient to save my psk can I?

Config of my wpa_supplicant:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1
```

Answer (score -2):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I know how to fix this.

First, you have to make sure that you didn't change anything in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Then you have to go to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/action_wpa.sh` and change the **IFACE** variable to

```
"$(cat /var/run/network/ifstate.wlp2s0)"
```

instead of

```
"${CTRL}#/run/wpa_supplicant"
```

Reboot your system and you will be able to use `wpa_cli` functions. But `nmcli` conflicts with `wpa_cli`, so don't use `wpa_cli` to reconnect or connect.
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/QGb8Cs3RMHVXs40VbZ1JCJv4PXG5VQbthB5SUB4NpwrfCj9_xwfZQQbP5wVT95fZllbb_sVQuXlTYiI=w1366-h620

Comment: Won't the interface name `wlp2s0` be different for others? Can you make sure this answer will work for OP and anyone else?

Comment: i thought you use ubuntu,if not there is another bug.my android was not be able to connect to wpa_supplicant and it couldn't boot wifi.

Comment: Oh yes your answer only needs to work for Ubuntu users, but in the config you put `cat /var/run/network/ifstate.wlp2s0` - I am not sure this is portable as others may not have the same interface name. Or will it always be `wlp2s0`?

Comment: control interface is your choice but wpa_cli just work with certain interface which is the same in wpa_supplicant.conf but sometimes it replaced the wlan0 or wlp2s0 to a path and that path can be not exist in differential systems.However wpa_supplicant can read the standard plain-text after update-config or similar variables.change ctrl_interface to wlan0.